# how to add multiselect functionality in d3 using mouse drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multi-select, force-layout

[image: directed graph]i have an application where i am making a directed graph using D3.js. The graph is solving my purpose fully,it is a directed graph which forms a mesh like structure.Now i want to select multiple nodes of this application using mouse drag,and also want their values to be printed in the console.This is my application..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.link {
fill: none;
stroke: #666;
stroke-width: 1.5px; 
}

  #licensing {
 fill: green;
 }

  .link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
  }

 .link.resolved {
 stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1; 
 }

  circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

   text {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
   pointer-events: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
   }
  </style>
  <body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
// http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/

/*Here licensing type is making the green arrow
 *Here resolved type is making the solid arrow
 *Here suit type is making the dotted arrow
 *
 *
 **/

var links = [ {
    source : "Microsoft",
    target : "Amazon",
    type : "licensing"
}, {
    source : "Microsoft",
    target : "HTC",
    type : "licensing"
}, {
    source : "Samsung",
    target : "Apple",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Motorola",
    target : "Apple",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Nokia",
    target : "Apple",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "HTC",
    target : "Apple",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Kodak",
    target : "Apple",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Microsoft",
    target : "Barnes & Noble",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Microsoft",
    target : "Foxconn",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Apple",
    target : "HTC",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Microsoft",
    target : "Inventec",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Samsung",
    target : "Kodak",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "LG",
    target : "Kodak",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "RIM",
    target : "Kodak",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Sony",
    target : "LG",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Kodak",
    target : "LG",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "Apple",
    target : "Nokia",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "Qualcomm",
    target : "Nokia",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "Kodak",
    target : "Samsung",
    type : "resolved"
}, {
    source : "Apple",
    target : "Samsung",
    type : "suit"
}, {
    source : "Kodak",
    target : "RIM",
    type : "licensing"
}, {
    source : "Kodak",
    target : "Qualcomm",
    type : "licensing"
} ];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
        name : link.source
    });
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
        name : link.target
    });
});

var width = 960, height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(d3.values(nodes)).links(links)
        .size([ width, height ]).linkDistance(60).charge(-300).on(
                "tick", tick).start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
        "height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker").data(
        [ "suit", "licensing", "resolved" ]).enter().append("marker")
        .attr("id", function(d) {
            return d;
        }).attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10").attr("refX", 15).attr("refY",
                -1.5).attr("markerWidth", 6).attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto").append("path").attr("d",
                "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path").data(force.links())
        .enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "link " + d.type;
        }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
            return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
        });




var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("circle").attr("r", 6).call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("text").attr("x", 8).attr("y", ".31em").text(
                function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

   //selection is happening 
var selected = circle.filter(function(d) {
    return d.name;
});
//here i am getting all the nodes and sending to the console here i need a selector by which i will select a couple of nodes by mouse drag and then send them to the console 
selected.each(function(d) {
      // d contains the data for the node and this is the circle element
      console.log(d.name);
    });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x, dy = d.target.y - d.source.y, dr = Math
            .sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr
            + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }

</script>
```

Here when i am running the script all the nodes are coming to the console.but i want a selection here ,i want that i will select a few nodes by mouse drag and those values will come to the console.

Comment: These are two large chunks of code. You're much more likely to get an answer if you demonstrate some attempt at solving the problem and a specific issue you're struggling with.

Comment: yes thats write.i need the functionality of the second to the first but i can not manage the window.svg

Comment: actually  i can not use window.states = [ {
 x : 43,
 y : 67,
 label : "first"
}, {
 x : 340,
 y : 150,
 label : "second"  to the  var links = [ {
   source : "Microsoft",
   target : "Amazon",
   type : "licensing"
  }, {
   source : "Microsoft",
   target : "HTC",
   type :

Comment: As I've said, please make an attempt on your own first.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to integrate selection by mouse into this. I got you started with the brush behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yr9Zp/).

Comment: thanks for your help but i can not see any values in the console i just see [16:06:28.293] [object Array]
[16:06:28.305] [object Array]
[16:06:28.309] [object Array]
[16:06:28.317] [object Array]
[16:06:28.325] [object Array]
[16:06:28.339] [object Array]

Comment: All selected elements will have the class "selected". You can use that to get the data and do any other manipulations you like.

Comment: console.log(d3.selectAll("circle.selected")); here i should see all the selected values

Comment: No, you will see all the selected circles with this. The data can be accessed through `.data()`.

Comment: console.log(d3.selectAll(d.data())); will it be the write one?

Comment: i mean to say where i will add the .data() to show the elements???

Comment: `console.log(d3.selectAll("circle.selected").data());` -- could you please make an attempt at solving this yourself? SO is for specific problems, not to provide complete solutions based on high-level specifications. I can do that as well, but will charge my normal consultancy fee.

Comment: ok no problem  info2jeet@gmail.com is my mail id  we can discuss over there about it